# Programming concision: "To replace the use of deprecated methods, for more up-do-date methods"

Tags: phrases, programming, concision

I was refactoring some old code and a lot of it used deprecated methods which had to be re-written to use more appropriate non-deprecated methods. When writing a changelog, it felt awkward writing such a long sentence.

Is there a word or a less verbose phrase for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use something like

*Refactor to non-deprecated methods.*

Refactor implies a change that doesn't affect behavior (as should be the case here).  The rest  is a concise description of the types of changes.